# What are the best resources online and offline to learn about drones?

Tags: photography

I'm looking to buy a drone, just as a hobby and take some aerial photos. But I know zilch about them.

Is there any place on the net or even some offline source such as a book which teaches me all there is to know about drones and drone photography? Some place where all technical terminologies and nuances are explained.

Comment: [This](https://www.dronegenuity.com/drone-video-tutorials/), [this](https://uavcoach.com/how-to-fly-a-quadcopter-guide/#guide-7), [this](https://maker.pro/custom/tutorial/how-to-make-a-drone-list-of-online-tutorials)... You can find dozens of tutorials by simply googling "drone tutorial beginner," but the real answer is there is nowhere you are going to find a single source which tells you all there is to know about drones; there is simply too much information, and new stuff is being invented / discovered every day.  Start somewhere, and when you run into issues, ask the question here. :D

Answer (score 2):

Start with getting your license (A1-A3 and later maybe A2), you can do that online and it will give you the first basic info, and will actually allow you to fly. It is not difficult nor expensive. If you understand the first basics of flying styles you can focus on that on YouTube video's and such. Don't worry, there is an overload of info available. Personally I have liked "joshua bardwell" and "painless360" although the latter is mainly for fixed wings and the first is for freestyle flying. Nevertheless they are informative IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as two separate types of information. One about drones and one about aerial photography.

### Photography

There are numerous drones on the market that have some sort of camera. The ones labeled as 'FPV' (First Person View) will have a streaming video camera. These may or may not have the ability to take still shots, but you could always grab some from the recorded video. These inbuilt cameras can have various capabilities / performance such as MegaPixels, Lens Type, Focus and F-Stop, etc. So there may be little to no control over the quality of the pictures.

### Drone

Most of the details about flying are the same as any plane, helicopter , etc. There are not that many that you need to know to simply fly a pre-built unit.

The answer above to just get one and start is pretty good. Do check the regulations in your area about registration and licenses. In the USA, a hobby pilot does not need a license and a Drone weighing less than 250g does not need to be registered. **However**, there are rules that must be followed, so always check before flying.

### Startup

There are several "toy / beginner" drones that are inexpensive and can take some abuse without breaking. They may not have cameras but it is a cheap way to start some research.

A step up in performance would be an "FPV" drone that has video (requiring a phone/tablet). These can be found for less than $150 and have some helpful features to "auto" fly.

Jump in and then come back for questions.